# argparse: How to get positional argument with name that can't be accessed normally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

How can I get the argument `"IP/DOMAIN"` without renaming it? I don't want to rename it because I want `-h` to specifically show `"IP/DOMAIN"` and not something else like `"IP_DOMAIN"`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('PORT', help='')
parser.add_argument('IP/DOMAIN', help='')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I can do:

```
args.PORT
```

But I can't do:

```
args.IP/DOMAIN
```

What also didn't work:

```
args["IP/DOMAIN"]
args[0]
```

Comment: You can separately control how args are named in the final object and in usage messages: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple setup:

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: a1 = parser.add_argument('IP/DOMAIN')
In [4]: a2 = parser.add_argument('easy', metavar='IP/DOMAIN')
```

With `metavar` we can provide an easy to use `dest`:

```
In [5]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] IP/DOMAIN IP/DOMAIN

positional arguments:
  IP/DOMAIN
  IP/DOMAIN

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Look at the parsing result:

```
In [6]: arg = parser.parse_args('foo bar'.split())
In [7]: arg
Out[7]: Namespace(easy='bar', **{'IP/DOMAIN': 'foo'})
```

If the name is simple, a valid Python variable, we can use the attribute access:

```
In [8]: arg.easy
Out[8]: 'bar'
```

But for general use, `getattr` works.  `argparse` actually uses this (and `setattr`) to minimize its assumptions about your `dest`:

```
In [9]: getattr(arg, 'IP/DOMAIN')
Out[9]: 'foo'
```

We can also convert the namespace to a `dict`:

```
In [10]: vars(arg)
Out[10]: {'IP/DOMAIN': 'foo', 'easy': 'bar'}
In [11]: vars(arg)['IP/DOMAIN']
Out[11]: 'foo'
```

Comment: Thank you. I somehow overlooked `metavar` and have not seen `getattr` before.